# I need to echo much in javascript by 1 function

Tags: javascript

I need to echo to much id `

```html
<p id='test'></p>
<p id='test'></p>
<script>document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD";</script>
```

` Please help :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to select multiple elements, try using the `querySelectorAll()`[*[MDN]*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method. Typically the `id` attribute should be unique, so you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id`, but that is a different topic/discussion entirely.

After getting all of the elements with `querySelectorAll()`, you will then want to perform an action on each of them. As far as I know there is not a way to perform the same action on multiple elements all at once. They will have to be done one at a time, which can be done using `forEach()`[*[MDN]*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on your list of elements.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#test").forEach(el => {
  el.innerHTML = "HELLO WORLD";
});
```

```html
<p id='test'></p>
<p id='test'></p>
```